# Authenticate iOS App with Internal Application Credentials NOT User Credentials

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

Is it possible for me to authenticate an iOS App without user interaction to the level where it can make Facebook requests for Page data?

For example, in an app for a musician, I would like to be able to make facebook requests for the musician's artist page including wall posts. I could then get the raw data for their page and style it however I please. This wouldn't require a user to log in and session authentication would be done asynchronously by the app itself, using embedded credentials.

I'd like to use the SDK but am thinking this would require manual OAuth Access Token requests and posts.

Thanks for the help!

---

UPDATE:

To clarify, I am curious about the possibility of the following:

1) App loads and makes a request for an OAuth Access Token using credentials baked into the App
2) App can then make requests to facebook for feed data from a predetermined page feed
3) None of this requires any user interaction or bounces the application to mobile safari, etc.

Comment: I take it you're working with the artist to develop an app with a nicer front-end to their FB page? Or are you trying to solve some other problem? What rights do you intend this credential to have? Is the app posting (as whom? to what wall?), or just reading?

Comment: Yes - would be a way to skin their facebook wall. Honestly, just being able to display the wall at all without a UIWebView would be fine. The credentials would be coming from the artist's label. The app would never POST on its own, only REQUEST the page's feed. If a USER using the app wants to then authenticate they could comment etc. but lets see if I can even just reed the feed first! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I figured this out. Feel pretty silly that I didn't know you could do this.

You can request an access token for an app id & secret. This will allow you to make public data requests that require an access token.

TO REQUEST ACCESS TOKEN: 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=11111111&client_secret=9999999999

Then, simply use the returned Access Token in your Feed Request:

https://graph.facebook.com/musicpage/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

If this is against TOS or deprecated - please let me know. For now this seems like the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand what you want, but it is possible to authenticate without user interaction:

> If the request requires authentication in order to make the
>   connection, valid credentials must already be available in the
>   NSURLCredentialStorage, or must be provided as part of the requested
>   URL. If the credentials are not available or fail to authenticate, the
>   URL loading system responds by sending the NSURLProtocol subclass
>   handling the connection a
>   continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge: message.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1

There is a way for authentication:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
   return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
     if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
         [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
     [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: Cool - never seen NSURLCredentialStorage before. How would this be applied to facebook? I must need to store credentials manually in NSURLCredentialStorage, correct? Would this be the Artist's username & password or some sort of facebook specific application credentials?